# Memory profiler linked to your application

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, profiler

Is there any .NET memory profiler or library that allows linking to your application and writing memory samples for that application programmatically without installing anything on the target machine. And analysing these sample later on another computer.

Thanks!

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: You may want to ask about your real problem. I mean the one that you are hoping to solve with the memory dumps.

Comment: Real problem is that have some problems written mostly not by me that has memory problems under load on remote host I don't have the possibility to install anything at. But these problems don't reproduce (or at least aren't obvious) in test enviroment, at least the part I'm capable to setup locally. So I would like anything that'll allow to single out the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture a memory dump of the offending process on the remote machine and then analyse the dump using WinDbg / sos.dll (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) on your local machine.

The SOS debugging extension will (among other functionality):

- Give you statistics on the managed heap such as generation sizes, type names / allocation size, etc.
- Allow you to trace the roots to objects on the managed heap which may give you clues as to which parts of your app are responsible for excessive memory allocation.